# Raspberry Pi W Zero HID by USB socket

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w

I’m currently working on a Bluetooth bridge device. For this purpose I have soldered a male USB to the USB TP (Test Points) on the Raspberry Pi PCB, see image. I’d like to power and send HID keystrokes/mouse movements through that USB.

[PCB image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/0585/files/PiZeroConnections_large.jpg?14913446398312428817)

Currently I have followed tutorials that centers around writing to `/dev/hidg0` which is for the micro USB output to send HID codes. However, I have not been able to figure out how to send HID codes through the new USB socket.

Has someone insights into how to work this out?

I appreciate any help that can guide me into the right direction.